# ListBox getting Height 1px when setting MinWidth

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

When setting the MinWidth property of a ListBox, the Height (which is set to auto) increases to 1px. Is there a good way of preventing this? I wish for an empty ListBox to hold the MinWidth value of 100 but stay hidden when no content is in it, instead of appearing as a 1px line.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

1.set BorderThickness = 0,Margin=0.
Some WPF Controls have default borderthickness or margin.

2.Why not use Visibility? When you set Visibility = Collapse,Listbox will not join layout process.